# How can I save an Image url from an API request to my core data?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

So im trying to create a favorite tab where the user can mark which Anime is there favorite and it will display on the Favorite tab view controller. I was able to get the title, synopsis (both label) but I cannot get the poster image (UIImageview) to my core data. I setted the poster attribute to binary but I dont know where to go next. these are my files:

> import UIKit
> import AlamofireImage
> import CoreData

class AnimeDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var backdropview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var posterview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titlelabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var synopsislabel: UILabel!

var anime: [String:Any]!
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
//var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController?


@IBAction func AddFav(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let mainView = navigationController?.parent?.view else { return }
    let hudView = HudView.hud(inView: mainView, animated: true)
    hudView.text = "Added"
      afterDelay(2) {
        hudView.hide()
      }
    //MARK: poster image help
    let att = anime["attributes"] as! NSDictionary
    let poster = att["posterImage"] as! NSDictionary
    let posterimage = poster["medium"] as! String
    let posterUrl = URL(string: posterimage)!
    CoreDataHelper.save(name: titlelabel.text!, synopsis: synopsislabel.text!, poster: posterview.af.setImage(withURL: posterUrl))

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    let att = anime["attributes"] as! NSDictionary
    let poster = att["posterImage"] as! NSDictionary
    let posterimage = poster["medium"] as! String
    let posterUrl = URL(string: posterimage)!
    
    if let backposter = att["coverImage"] as? NSDictionary{
        let backimage = backposter["original"] as! String
        let backUrl = URL(string: backimage)!
        backdropview.af.setImage(withURL: backUrl)
    }

    
    
    titlelabel.text = att["canonicalTitle"] as? String
    
    synopsislabel.text = att["synopsis"] as? String
    posterview.af.setImage(withURL: posterUrl)
    
    
}
```

}

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

struct CoreDataHelper {
    static func save(name: String, synopsis: String, poster: Data) { //need to add third arg. poster: String
      guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
      }
      // 1
      let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
      // 2
      let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Favorite",
                                   in: managedContext)!
      let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                   insertInto: managedContext)
      // 3
      person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "title")
      person.setValue(synopsis, forKeyPath: "synopsis")
      person.setValue(synopsis, forKeyPath: "poster")
      // 4
      do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("saved")
      } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit

class FavTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var favposterView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var favtitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var favsumLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavAnimeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var favorites = [NSManagedObject]()
    var numAnime = 0
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        load()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    
    func load() {
        //1
        guard let appDelegate =
                UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        //2
        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Favorite")
        //3
        do {
            favorites = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favorites.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:  "FavTableViewCell") as! FavTableViewCell
        
        let favAnime = favorites[indexPath.row]
       
        cell.favtitleLabel.text = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "title") as? String
        cell.favsumLabel.text = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "synopsis") as? String
       // cell.favposterView = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "poster") as? String problem here

        

        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

if anyone could help that be amazing

Comment: Just to clarify, is the problem that you don't know how to store data in Core Data or that you don't know how to serialize a `UIImage`?  I would infer the latter, but just want to be sure.

Comment: @ChipJarred I dont know how to store it in the core data. Im gonna upload another code snippet which shows when im setting the value to the attribute core data

Answer (score 0):

First let's address a bug in your code.  You're setting your synopsis *twice*.  Once for the key, "synopsis", which would be correct, and on the next line, you set it again for the key, "poster", which is the wrong part.

```swift
static func save(name: String, synopsis: String, poster: Data) {
...
        person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "title")
        person.setValue(synopsis, forKeyPath: "synopsis")
        /* Change this
        person.setValue(synopsis, forKeyPath: "poster") 
        to this */
        person.setValue(poster, forKeyPath: "poster") 
...
}
```

That bug is probably the main problem you're having.  After that you could probably figure the rest out, but I'm not going to leave you hanging.

So next there's what to do in `FavAnimeViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.  You commented out the problematic line, but it still won't work.  `poster` is not a string.  It's `Data`.  actually, it should be `UIImage` (or `NSImage` for macOS), but for now I'm assuming that you have a way to convert from `Data` to `UIImage` and back.

So change this line *from*

```swift
// cell.favposterView = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "poster") as? String problem here
```

*to*

```swift
if let imageData = favAnime.value(forKeyPath: "poster") as? Data {
    cell.favposterView = posterViewFromImageData(imageData)
}
else { cellfavposterView = someDefaultPosterView }
```

Here I'm assuming that `posterViewFromImageData(_:)` is a function that you have, probably under a different name, that converts a `Data` to `UIImage` or whatever `cellfavposterView` is, and `someDefaultPosterView` is a view you can use when things fail.

That should get things working, but it could be better.  For starters, you'd like to use `UIImage` with Core Data just like you use `String`, right?  So let's start with converting to `Data`.  Here's a technique I like to use:

```swift
extension Data
{
    init<T: NSCoding>(from source: T)
    {
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
        archiver.encode(source, forKey: "0")
        archiver.finishEncoding()
        
        self = archiver.encodedData
    }
    
    func decode<T:NSCoding>(to type: T.Type) -> T?
    {
        guard let unarchiver = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: self),
              let obj = unarchiver.decodeObject(of: [T.self], forKey: "0")
        else { return nil }
        
        return obj as? T
    }
}
```

Now we can convert anything that conforms to `NSCoding` to `Data` and back.  The key `"0"` can be anything, as long as it's the same in both cases.  Actually in real life I use `"\(T.self)"`.  We're encoding a single value, so we only need a key at all it to placate the archiver and unarchiver.  If this were `Codable` instead of `NSCoding`, I would use a singleValueContainer, but making classes conform to `Codable` can be problematic when inheritance is involved and you don't own their definition, because the required `init` can't be defined in an `extension`.  So for anything that's part of AppKit or UIKit, I invert the responsibility for encoding/decoding by going through my extension on `Data`.

You can now covert a `UIImage` to and from `Data` like this.:

```swift
let data = Data(from: someUIImage)
guard let recoveredImage = data.decode(to: UIImage.self) else {
    fatalError("Do something meaningful on failure")
}
```

If you have your own way that you prefer, just replace my usage of this `extension` in what follows with your own method.

To have Code Data deal with `UIImage` automatically, you need to register a way to transform it to and from `Data`, so first define a transformer:

```swift
class UIImageTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer
{
    public override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        return (value as? Data)?.decode(to: UIImage.self)
    }
    
    public override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any?
    {
        guard let image = value as? UIImage else { return nil }
        return Data(from: image)
    }
}
```

Then you have to set up a value transformer name

```swift
extension NSValueTransformerName
{
    static var imageToNameTransformer: NSValueTransformerName {
        .init("imageToNameTransformer")
    }
}
```

Then in `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunching()`, or at least some point early in your program before you load your Core Data stack:

```swift
ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(UIImageTransformer(), forName: .imageToNameTransformer)
```

Now Core Data knows how to convert directly to and from a `UIImage`.  You'll need to modify the code we fixed above to use `UIImage` instead of `Data`.

Comment: I dont have a posterViewFromImageData(_:) function to convert Data to UIImage nor idk how to. Im looking up online on how to do it but its conflicting with my code. I know the function has to be in my FavAnimeViewController but exactly how the function should look like ;-;

Comment: Well if you can build a posterView given a `UIImage`, then my extension on `Data` can give you a `UIImage` from `Data`... assuming you use the extension to convert the `UIImage` to `Data` in the first place.   But the point of the `ValueTransformer` is to have Core Data do that conversion for you.

Comment: @ChippJarred Ah I see, so then i dont really need posterViewFromImageData(_:) anymore. for let data = Data(from: someUIImage), what exactly am i putting for someUIImage? and when i call my coredatahelper in my animesViewController, is the poster parameter still going to be poster: posterview.af.setImage(withURL: posterUrl)?

Comment: The snippet with `someUIImage` was just an example of using the extension on `Data`.  The first line converts to `Data`, and the second line converts from `Data`.  It's meant for you to apply wherever you need to convert `UIImage` (or any other class that conforms to `NSCoding`) to or from `Data`... As to setting the poster image, well I've been assuming that you want to save the image, not the URL to it.  So the way my solution is framed, you'd set it with the image itself not with the URL.   However, if you want to use the URL, then you save the URL instead of the image in CoreData.

Comment: BTW - there's a pros and cons to referring to the poster image by URL.  As a pro, if the online image is updated, you'll always get the new one.  The "cons" are that it will always involve network access to get the actual image which isn't necessary if you save the image locally, and if the image is ever deleted online, the URL will no longer point to anything meaningful... unless the URL is a `file:` URL.

Comment: okay cool! I'll try to utilize all this information and see what I can do (: Thanks so much!

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question about `someUIImage`.   Presumably at the point when you want to save the image, your `posterView` is a `UIImageView`, so `someUIImage` is just the image you extract from the `UIImageView`.   Then when you load the data, you initialize the posterView using the image instead of a URL.  I'm assuming the URL is a network URL.  If its actually a local file, then all of this is simpler, because you can just save the URL instead, or even URL.path, which his a `String`.